# Error in the update statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, syntax-error

I have this below query. When I try to execute it, I see this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Query:

```
UPDATE T
SET T.COUNTRY_ID = DS.COUNTRY_ID,
    T.GEO_CUST_COUNTRY_ID = DS.GEO_CUST_COUNTRY_ID
FROM
    DS_TRANS DS, TRANSACTIONS T
WHERE
    DS.ID = T.ID
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: This works fine though. UPDATE T
    SET
        T.COUNTRY_ID = DS.COUNTRY_ID
        FROM
    DS_TRANS DS, TRANSACTIONS T
WHERE
    DS.ID=T.ID

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Comma before the `FROM` clause is the issue.</strike>

More over you can use JOIN instead of the comma separated tables.

So the working code will be:

```
UPDATE T
SET T.COUNTRY_ID = DS.COUNTRY_ID,
    T.GEO_CUST_COUNTRY_ID = DS.GEO_CUST_COUNTRY_ID
FROM TRANSACTIONS T
JOIN DS_TRANS DS ON DS.ID = T.ID
```

Comment: sorry I pasted that comma by mistake in this portal, but my actually query doesnt contains it.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that SQL Server does not allow old style pre ANSI-92 style joins in an `UPDATE` statement.  Try switching your query to use an explicit `INNER JOIN`:

```
UPDATE T
SET
    T.COUNTRY_ID = DS.COUNTRY_ID,
    T.GEO_CUST_COUNTRY_ID = DS.GEO_CUST_COUNTRY_ID
FROM
    DS_TRANS DS
    INNER JOIN TRANSACTIONS T
        ON DS.ID = T.ID
```